# Android Emulator set GPS values

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, gps

I tried the whole day to run two tutorials on my Google API 7 Emulator. I can send GPS values via DDMS and telnet, but on any higher API device this function doesnt work. Does anyone has an idea on what could be the problem? Cause i need a higher device foy my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android 2.3.x emulator (API Levels 9 and 10) have a bug where DDMS/telnet does not work for geo fixes, and there is no known workaround, other than to buy and test on hardware.

I have not had problems with Android 2.2 (API Level 8). I have not had GPS-specific problems with Android 3.x emulators, but they are terribly slow.

Comment: yes they are way to slow... i allready read sth like that but i didnt want to believe it, thx for the reply